# How does configuring bind ip to localhost secures MongoDB instance?

Tags: security, mongodb

Starting in MongoDB 3.6, MongoDB binaries, mongod and mongos, bind to localhost by default. How does it ensure security of MongoDB database?

Answer (score 2):

It only limits the default access to the IP range of the localhost, so that you cannot connect from a remote computer to the database.
You still have to take care to secure the access to your database, based on users and which data those users are allowed to gather. After that you can open your network access to MonogDB.

I guess this changed was made due to [a lot MongoDB instances were not secured and reachable over the internet](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/11/mongodb_ransomware_followup/). So the default to listen on localhost only is just for the initial configuration, maybe some weren't aware that the instance was reachable and only needed the database on the localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and informative answer . According to description as mentioned into above answer limiting access to localhost will allow mongodb databases to be accessible only from localhost server and will be blocked upon request from remote server